# What word processor can manage left and right pages separately?

Tags: libreoffice, text-editor, editing

I was after a word processor that can manage left and right pages separately so I can have my text on the right pages and my illustrations on the left pages.
I know LibeOffice can set "left page" and "right page" formats, but there is no simple way to make the text jump from right page to right page when writing.
I don't know what would be the best way to do that, but I guess I need an app that is designed for writing books and do that kind of thing, or an app that can associate a page format with an object format (so the "illustration" format can be exclusively associated with "left page" format, and "text body" exclusively associated with "right page", for example).
Or is there an extension for LO or OOo out there that I didn't hear about?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best workaround I found on LO:

1 - Create two page styles:

```
"Left illustration page"

"Right text page"
```

Assign next style for left illustration page: right text page

Assign next style right text page: left illustration page

2 - Insert a borderless frame in the header of any of the pages with the "left illustration page" style. This frame has to fill the entire page, so that the text written on the right pages jumps directly to the next right page, leaving the left page blank. As this frame is included in the header, it will be part of the page style.

3 - To add illustrations on the left pages: Insert an image in the frame, which is then visible on all left pages -> right click on it and anchor it to the page so that it appears only on the desired page. Another way to do it without inserting it in all pages in the first place is to insert it in a right page, anchor it to the page, cut it and paste it in the left page frame.

I hope this can help people in the same case!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any current extension for LO or OO with such implementation, though you can try [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus), which is desktop publishing software and should meet your requirements. But then again, I'm not sure whether you'll find it easy to manage or not :P